# Configuring async loggers in log4j2.properties

Tags: logging, properties, log4j2

I want to make some loggers asynchronous in log4j2.properties file. In the xml format you can add as

```
<Loggers>
    <AsyncLogger name="com.foo.Bar" level="info">
    </AsyncLogger>
</Loggers>
```

I tried it in log4j2.properties as 
loggers = com-foo-Bar

```
asyncLogger.com-foo-Bar.name = com.foo.Bar
asyncLogger.com-foo-Bar.level = INFO
```

But this syntax seems to be wrong.

What is the correct way to configure it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is one way of using `AsyncLogger` in `log4j2 properties` file -

```
logger.com.foo.Bar.type = AsyncLogger
logger.com.foo.Bar.name = com.foo.Bar
logger.com.foo.Bar.level = info
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do I know that the AsyncLoggers are being used. I debugged with breakpoints in org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger but it didn't get hit.

Comment: enable debug or trace logs by changing `status` in `log4j2.properties` file - `status = debug` then in logs, you can see `AsyncLogger` is getting created.